# Vertical Scrollbar not showing with Turbolinks on

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a Rails 4.2 application with turbolinks on and when I load any page, it shows the scrollbar correctly.

After I click on any link, the scrollbar disappears and nothing I do will make it show again. I tried setting it up using Coffee, using CSS, but nothing makes it show up, unless I disable turbolinks.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?